# Next.js 13.4.5 deployment: Redirects appending ".txt" to page names in URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm currently facing an issue with redirects in my Next.js 13.4.5 deployment to Firebase. I have configured my Next.js application to output as a static export using the following configuration in my next.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

However, after deploying my application to Firebase, I noticed that the redirects are appending ".txt" to the page names in the URL. For example, instead of redirecting to http://localhost:3000/dashboard, the URL becomes http://localhost:3000/dashboard.txt.

I expected the redirect to function properly as a client-side redirect using router.push() in Next.js, without modifying the URL with the ".txt" extension.

I have checked my redirect configurations, and they seem to be correct. Is there something I'm missing in my deployment setup or configuration that could be causing this issue?

Comment: Same thing here. Don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this bug has been a thing since nextjs 13.3.0. In short, `output: 'export'` doesn't support dynamic routing. There is a bug logged in github. You may look it up for more information and work arounds like I did.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48022

edit: I just noticed that in your question, the exemple does not have a dynamic route. I was having this issue myself so I took for granted the fact it was a dynamic route. Hope my answer help regardless